# Passing values to dynamic query in SQL Server procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamic

```
CREATE TYPE TableVariable AS TABLE
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    field_ids        INT,
    value    VARCHAR(MAX)
)

Type created successfully.

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
Alter PROCEDURE Testing
(
    @TableVar TableVariable READONLY,
    @C_id INT


)
AS
Declare @maxPK INT;
Declare @pk INT;
Declare @fid INT;
Declare @val VARCHAR(max);
Declare @Where VARCHAR(max);
Declare @SQL VARCHAR(MAX);
Set @pk = 1
BEGIN
   BEGIN TRY
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
     Select @maxPK = count(*) From @TableVar 
     SELECT @maxPK
     SELECT @C_id

         Set @SQL = 'SELECT DISTINCT v1.e_id from values v1 inner join listings l ON v1.e_id = 
         l.e_id WHERE l.c_id='+ @C_id
         SELECT @SQL
While @pk <= @maxPK
BEGIN


     SELECT @fid= field_ids FROM @TableVar where id=@pk;
     SELECT @val= value     FROM @TableVar where id=@pk;
     SELECT @fid
     SELECT @val
     SET @SQL += ' and exists  (select 1 from values v@pk+1 where v1.e_id = @pk+1.e_id and @pk+1.f_id=@fid and(value=@val))' 
     Select @pk = @pk + 1

END
     SELECT @SQL
     EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

    END CATCH
END

DECLARE @DepartmentTVP AS TableVariable;

INSERT INTO @DepartmentTVP VALUES (14567, 'first')
INSERT INTO @DepartmentTVP VALUES (145678, 'second')

SELECT * 
FROM @DepartmentTVP

EXEC Testing @DepartmentTVP, 83
```

I executed the above procedure.Values are not passed to the query

This is my orginal query

```
select distinct 
    v1.e_id 
from 
    values v1 
inner join 
    listings l on v1.e_id = l.e_id   
where 
   l.c_id = 83 
   and exists (select 1 
               from values v2 
               where v1.e_id = v2.e_id 
                 and v2.f_id = 1780 
                 and (value = N'Peppermint Whole Care Toothpaste')) 
   and exists (select 1 
               from values v3 
               where v1.e_id = v3.e_id  
                 and v3.f_id = 22483 
                 and (value = N'sasdfa'))  
 order by 
     l.id desc
```

and exists part will add dynamically.

Comment: parameter value c_id is not passed into the query and it is not returning results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting a variable to be part of the text such as:

```
'select 1 from values v@pk+1 where v1.e_id = @pk+1.e_id'
```

Then you need to escape the string and add the variable -- but beware this is prone to SQL Injection attacks if you don't strictly control the source of the variable data!

Example:

```
'select 1 from values v'+convert(varchar(15),@pk+1)+' where v1.e_id = '+convert(varchar(15),@pk+1)+'.e_id'
```

If you simply want to pass the variable into the string such as:

```
'and v5.f_id=@fid and(value=@val))'
```

Then you leave those variables unescaped, and pass them into `sp_executesql`

Example:

```
exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@fid int, @val varchar(max)', @fid=@fid, @val=@val
```

More info on `sp_executesql` and its parameters:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql